# Ubuntu ArmHF vs arm64

Tags: ubuntu

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#arm64

The website raspberry pi images:

1. ArmHF
2. arm64

   - What is the difference between the two?
   - Are both 64 bit operating systems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are both 64 bit operating systems?

No, `arm64` is a `64bit` architecture and on the other hand, `armhf` is a `32bit` architecture.
However, you can install one of them and next, install Multiarch to feel free on it.

---

> Multiarch lets you install library packages from multiple
>   architectures on the same machine. This is useful in various ways, but
>   the most common is installing both 64 and 32-bit software on the same
>   machine and having dependencies correctly resolved automatically. In
>   general, you can have libraries of more than one architecture installed
>   together and applications from one architecture or another installed
>   as alternatives. Note that it does not enable multiple architecture
>   versions of applications to be installed simultaneously.

https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

---

Check [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) out to get more details.
Read [the story here](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi). It would be helpful for your first question.